# Use custom blog or prebuilt blog (e.g. WordPress MU) on a new CodeIgniter PHP site?

Tags: php, codeigniter, blogs

I asked this very same question on PHP forum to which I got no response.

In terms of:

- time spent on programming
- performance of blog
- flexibility

would it make sense to build a blog on codeigniter from scratch or integrate an existing WordPress blogging software with the codeigniter site? Reason why I ask because if you want to only have one log in and have admin approval based on admin from site, you come across problems when trying to integrate blogging software which has its own tables for things. Importantly, what if you want a clean database design not be influenced by external blogging software, generating its own tables? Modifying existing blogging software can be just as time consume as building one custom for your site, I believe.

In terms of the three criteria above, which would you believe is more effective approach?

THanks for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think their are plenty of blog/CMS solutions available, already built on codeigniter, that you'd be better off staying away from mixing platforms, which can get messy and create a big headache down the road if you don't properly document your steps of integration.

A few to get you looking

- [PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com) - basically the defacto standard for Free(Beer and Speach) CMS for CI
- [BLogmer](http://speedovation.org/) - A blogging platform written on CI that I found after a quick google search

Comment: Have examples of code blog solutions for codeigniter that excel in performance and flexibility?

Comment: I think it's going to be hard to find CodeIgniter Projects that do *NOT* excel in performance and flexibility, which is CI's claim to fame.

Comment: My major concern is scalability. I will have an authentication system already in place. When I integrate this blog, I don't want to force the app to work around the blog. I want the blog to work around the app. That means one users table containing users who are linked to roles. I hope BLogmer can accomodate this because wordpress surely couldn't. My main concern is if it influences database design.

Comment: keep in mind that you can have multiple database configs for CI.